# When should TERM be set to alacritty-direct

Tags: arch-linux, emacs, alacritty

I am using alacritty 0.11.0 (8dbaa0bb) on Arch.

the default `TERM` type is `alacritty`, which works well (truecolors etc) for everything except terminal emacs. In a terminal emacs does not show truecolors.

However if I `export TERM=alacritty-direct` then everything, including emacs, works fine AFAICT.

What is the purpose of `alacritty-direct` and when should it be used?

I currently have this in my `.zshrc`

```
[[ "${TERM}" == "alacritty" ]] && export TERM=alacritty-direct
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `$TERM` is to **inform programs** about what the terminal allegedly supports. The terminal's actual capabilities do not change (it supports direct color at all times), but many programs such as Emacs will look at $TERM and query the associated 'terminfo' database to determine whether they *should* use direct color mode or not.

So you should set TERM to "alacritty-direct" when you want such programs to be able to detect direct-color mode.

(Ideally your terminal itself should be setting TERM to your desired value, so that it would be in effect even when the terminal is asked to directly start non-shell programs, but if you only ever use the terminal in the "normal" way then your ~/.zshrc entry is probably good enough.)

You can use `infocmp [-L] <name>` to print the terminfo database entry for a specific terminal, or specify two names to have infocmp compare them. You'll see that the two entries for alacritty mostly differ in `setaf` and `setab` properties ('set_a_background' and 'set_a_foreground').

```
$ infocmp -L alacritty alacritty-direct
comparing alacritty to alacritty-direct.
    comparing booleans.
    can_change: T:F.
    comparing numbers.
    max_colors: 256, 16777216.
    comparing strings.
    initialize_color: '\E]4;%p1%d;rgb\072%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\E\',
                      NULL.
    orig_colors: '\E]104^G', NULL.
    reset_1string: '\Ec\E]104^G', '\Ec'.
    set_a_background: '\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t4%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;%p1%d%;m',
                      '\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t4%p1%d%e48;2;%p1%{65536}%/%d;%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&%d;%p1%{255}%&%d%;m'.
    set_a_foreground: '\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;%p1%d%;m',
                      '\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e38;2;%p1%{65536}%/%d;%p1%{256}%/%{255}%&%d;%p1%{255}%&%d%;m'.
```

Of course, there are many programs that don't use terminfo but make hardcoded assumptions based on $TERM (e.g. they may have embedded assumptions that TERM=alacritty already indicates direct-color support), or even those which output direct-color sequences unconditionally, in which case there will be no visible effect between the 'alacritty' and 'alacritty-direct' values – again, the $TERM value does not actually make the terminal lose the support.

For example, in Vim it is common to manually `set termguicolors` to make it use direct-color mode regardless of what $TERM indicates, or to directly set various `t_*` variables (corresponding to 'termcap' parameters – a predecesor to terminfo still found on BSD systems).